# Prove using congruences that $ 7\mid\left(5^{2n}+3\cdot 2^{5n-2}\right)$ , $n \ge 1$

Tags: number-theory, induction, divisibility

Prove using congruences that:

## $$ 7\mid\left(5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2}\right)$$

(is divisible by 7)

So I'm trying to use mathematical induction to show that for all integers $n \ge 1$
but i cant prove this!!

Comment: Induction sounds like a good way.  Have you considered taking $n=7y+k$ for $k\in[0,1,\dots,6]$ to see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Claim : $$5^{2n}+3\times 2^{5n-2}\equiv 0\pmod 7$$ for $n\ge 1$

Base case : $25+3\times2^3=25+24=49\equiv 0\pmod 7$

Induction step

$$5^{2n+2}+3\times 2^{5n+3}=25\times 5^{2n}+96\times 2^{5n-2}=25\times(5^{2n}+3\times 2^{5n-2})+21\times 2^{5n-2}$$

I think you can finish the proof now.

Answer (score 2):

mod $7$: 
$\quad
5^{2n}+3\cdot2^{5n-2}
=  25^n +3\cdot \dfrac{32^n}{4}
\equiv  4^n +3\cdot 2 \cdot 4^n
\equiv  4^n - 4^n
\equiv 0
$

Comment: I liked this answer a lot and understand what is going on, but I am confused if we really can work with modular arithmetic and fractions like this. I am sure your work can just be reduced and is in fact equivalent to similar statements with only integers right?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Use that 
$$
5^{2(n+1)}+3 2^{5(n+1)-2}=25 \cdot 5^{2n}+32 \cdot  3 \cdot 2^{5n},
$$
and take into account that $25=32 \mod 7.$

Answer (score -2):

Let's call the expression $f(n)$. For $n=k$, assume that $7|f(k) \implies 7|5^{2k}+3\cdot2^{5k-2}$. Then multiply the expression by $5^2\cdot2^5$ and it is still divisible by $7$. So we get $2^{5}\cdot5^{2k+2}+5^{2}\cdot3\cdot2^{5k+3}$ which is equivalent to $4\cdot5^{2k+2}+4\cdot3\cdot2^{5k+3} \pmod 7$. $7$ divides the expression and $4$ and $7$ are co-primes. So,$7|5^{2k+2}+3\cdot2^{5k+3}$ and the last expression is equal to $f(k+1) (7|f(k+1))$.